# How can I select Page and all Images of that page where conditions are true

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, lambda

I have two table like this. 
[image]

I want to select `Pages` and `Images` where page and image status are true and matches with the PageId in both table.

I have tried this code

```
var data = entity.Pages.Join(entity.Images, page => page.Id, image => image.PageId, (page, image) => new { Page = page, Image = image }).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Page.Slug==url && x.Page.Status && x.Image.Status);
```

It selects page that I want and a first image. However I want to select the all images for that page. How can I do this? Is it possible to do this with one query?

If I use `Where` instead `FirstOrDefault` it returns me 
It returns 
`{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent1].[Slug] AS [Slug], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Title] AS [Title1], 
    [Extent2].[ImageUrl] AS [ImageUrl], 
    [Extent2].[PageId] AS [PageId], 
    [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId1], 
    [Extent2].[Status] AS [Status1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Pages] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PageId]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Slug] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Status] = 1) AND ([Extent2].[Status] = 1)}`

this.

How can I select Image or Page that I want from inside of it?

Comment: You're using `FirstOrDefault`, try with `Where` instead

Comment: @MilenPavlov I have edited it with `Where`.